# pd-extended package cant be found on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: software-installation, 14.10

i've newly upgraded from 14.04 to 14.10. now pd-extended has been removed and cant be installed via terminal. it doesnt actually exist enymore in the repository and software center. any idea of handling the problem?

thank you
regards

Answer (score 1):

Pure Data Extended hasn't been updated and is need of a new maintainer. Source: http://lists.puredata.info/pipermail/pd-list/2015-03/109361.html

If you want to install Pure Data Extended you have to manually install the version built for Ubuntu Trusty Tahir, which can be found here: http://apt.puredata.info/releases/dists/trusty/main/